# mouse events on image in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I have the following class in small talk

```
Object subclass: #SnookerBall
    instanceVariableNames: 'image type position'
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'mmn16'

initialize
    self initialize.
    image := ImageMorph new image: (Form fromFileNamed: 'ball_1.gif').
    image position:100@100.
```

now I want to implement the mouse events on the image. 
basically I need to simulate a snooker ball.
So I need the mouse events (clicked, dragged and so on) and make it look animated.

Please help
Thank you in advanced

Ok I have a SnookerBall class edited

```
ImageMorph subclass: #SnookerBall
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Snooker'
```

and initialize method

```
initialize
    self image: (Form fromFileNamed: 'ball_1.gif');
    extent:40@40;
    position:0@0.
```

I'm trying to execute:

```
b:=SnookerBall new.
b openInWorld.
```

and I have an error : MessageNotUnderstood: UndefinedObject>>hasPositiveExtent

please help

Comment: Depending on your requirements you could also make SnookerBall itself a proper Morph (e. g., by subclassing from ImageMorph) and override `handlesMouseDown:`, `mouseDown:` and friends. For that, see the "event handling" protocol (method category) in Morph. Also, the Squeak by Example book has a nice introduction on Morphs and event handling, if your classes are Morphs.

Comment: Please note that your initialize method has an infinite recursion because `self initialize` calls the same method again. You probably wanted to write `super initialize` instead (but since Object does not do anything in initialize you could also omit that line entirely).

Comment: if I inherit from ImageMorph how the drawOn method sould look like?
And abount the self initialize it's my mistake :)

Comment: If you only want to display the image from 'ball_1.gif' you do not have to do anything at all with `drawOn:` (i. e., do not override it). ImageMorph>>drawOn: will already handle that for you. Instead of `ImageMorph new image: ...` you will have to initialize your SnookerBall with `self image: ...`, then it should render the image.

Comment: Ok I'll try it now

Comment: It's not working I edited my post with the new code, please help

Comment: Now you are missing the `super initialize` call at the beginning of your initialize method. In contrast to Object, Morph does do important things in its own initialize method. When you forget to call super in a Morph's initialize, some instance variables will remain `nil` (which is the instance of UndefinedObject), hence your MessageNotUnderstood, I assume.

Comment: Hello can you share with me the source code for the snooker game project please in smalltalk? it will be of great help to me with this type of game in smalltalk.Please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Morph>>on:send:to:`:

```
SnookerBall>>
initialize
    "..."
    image on: #click send: #ballClicked to: self

ballClicked
    "pop up a modal dialog"
    self inform: 'Ball was clicked'
```

... to invoke `ballClicked` on the SnookerBall object when the ImageMorph is clicked.

Have a look at `EventHandler>>on:send:to:` to see the possible arguments for on: #mouseDown, #mouseMove, #click, ...

If you need an argument for the resulting message, consider `Morph>>on:send:to:withValue:`.

Comment: Thank you, and if I want to send the event to another class? means not to:self but to another class that represents the snooker table?

Comment: Correct, you would have to change the argument for to:. You need some way to make that table "known" to the SnookerBall, so it can install the event handler on image properly. As initialize takes no arguments, you would have to add another method in SnookerBall such as `table: aSnookerTable` with `image on: #click send: #ballClicked to: aSnookerTable` in its code. You would probably want to let the table know which particular ball has been clicked, so maybe make that `image on: #click send: #ballClicked: to: aSnookerTable withValue: self` (note the colon after ballClicked).